# How this array can be divided?

Tags: python, python-3.x

While I was trying to run this I am getting the following error

I imported `array` as `arr`

```
import array as arr
x = arr.array([3, 6, 9, 12])
x/3.0
print(x)
```

I expect the output to be

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Error:

```
x = arr.array([3, 6, 9, 12])
TypeError: array() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not list
```

Can anybody explain to me why this thing is not happening?

Comment: Well, as it says, the first argument to `array` needs to be a character indicating the type, such as `'f'` for float. But it looks like you might actually want a numpy array, not an `array.array`.

Comment: As a kind suggestion, I would urge you to go through the online documentation of the library you are using before posting a question to SO. It will make you solve  future errors like the present one faster and on your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 major problems here.

The first problem is that you are not initializing the array correctly. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html), you need to specify a unicode character as the first argument for the type code. Since you're only using the array to store integers, we'll use `i`. (You may want to just use a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) instead of an array, though.)

The second problem is that you need to modify each element in the array individually, as opposed to trying to divide the entire array by 3. For example:

```py
import array as arr
x = arr.array('i', [3, 6, 9, 12])
new_x = []
for element in x:
    new_x.append(element // 3)
print(new_x)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Note that `new_x` is a list, while `x` is an array.

Finally, one way to express this logic more concisely is with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
import array as arr
x = arr.array('i', [3, 6, 9, 12])
new_x = [element // 3 for element in x]
print(new_x)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks, man but I do have a question. Can you explain this new_x = [element // 3 for element in x]

Comment: That line is a list comprehension, which is basically a way of translating a list (x) to another list (new_x). This list comprehension translates to "for every element in x, append that element // 3 to a new array". The double slashes indicate floor division, so that the result will always be an integer. I will edit the post with a non-list comprehension example.

Comment: @RaktimKantiBhowmick Essentially, your `x/3` line did not work for 2 reasons: 1. `array` objects of python do no support division by a float/integer number. What you have to do to overcome this is to divide each element of the array on its own. 2. Even if it did work, `x/3` would not save the resulting values anywhere, same as `2+3` command won't. So @crash actually loops through the array, divides each element by 3, constructs a new array with the new elements and stores it in `new_x`, all in a single line by taking advantage the one-line loops for list creation of Python

Comment: It's worth explicitly stating that, although `x` is an array, `new_x` is a list (i.e. the two variables have different types). Although this fits the question as it is worded, in practice if `x` is only being constructed as a stepping stone towards `new_x` then it might as well be created as a plain list too (i.e. `x = [3, 6, 9, 12]`).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) the first argument needs to be the *type code*.

Details from there:

> ```
> Type code | C Type             | Python Type       | Minimum size in bytes | Notes
> 'b'       | signed char        | int               | 1                     |
> 'B'       | unsigned char      | int               | 1                     |
> 'u'       | Py_UNICODE         | Unicode character | 2                     | (1)
> 'h'       | signed short       | int               | 2                     |
> 'H'       | unsigned short     | int               | 2                     |
> 'i'       | signed int         | int               | 2                     |
> 'I'       | unsigned int       | int               | 2                     |
> 'l'       | signed long        | int               | 4                     |
> 'L'       | unsigned long      | int               | 4                     |
> 'q'       | signed long long   | int               | 8                     |
> 'Q'       | unsigned long long | int               | 8                     |
> 'f'       | float              | float             | 4                     |
> 'd'       | double             | float             | 8                     |
> ```
>
> Notes:
>
> 1. The 'u' type code corresponds to Python’s obsolete unicode character (Py_UNICODE > which is wchar_t). Depending on the platform, it can be 16 bits or 32 bits.
>
>    'u' will be removed together with the rest of the Py_UNICODE API.

and

> class array.array(**typecode**[, initializer])
>
> A new array whose items are restricted by typecode, and initialized from the optional initializer value, which must be a list, a bytes-like object, or iterable over elements of the appropriate type.
>
> If given a list or string, the initializer is passed to the new array’s fromlist(), frombytes(), or fromunicode() method (see below) to add initial items to the array. Otherwise, the iterable initializer is passed to the extend() method.